# On Cray systems running Linux, how can I submit multiple qsub requests using aprun in an automated BASH script?

Tags: linux, bash, batch-processing, qsub, cray

Specifically, Cray requires a special command (`aprun`) embedded within the `qsub` request to execute the job on a batch node (Cray defaults to running on login/compute nodes without the `aprun` syntax).  When hand-keying a `qsub` request to Cray Linux supercomputers, the directed syntax is:

```
qsub <qsub parameters> -V
aprun -n #CPUS /executable.exe param1 param2 ...
Ctrl-D
```

Where the user provides 'return' after the `-V` (denoting passage of parameters in the `qsub` statement) and after the executable/parameter set.  `Ctrl-D` terminates the input and executes the `qsub/aprun` command.

The problem is, there are a variety of ways described on the net for inputting the `Ctrl-D` (which simply means `EOF`) in a BASH script, but none of them work in the context of the `qsub`-embedded `aprun` command.

What I need to do is execute this same syntax for multiple `qsub/aprun` commands  in a single script.  How do I code this in BASH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution syntax is:

```
qsub <qsub parameters> -V <<EOF 
cd 
aprun -n #CPUS /executable.exe param1 param2 ... 
EOF 

qsub <qsub parameters> -V <<EOF 
cd 
aprun -n #CPUS /executable.exe param1 param2 ... 
EOF
```

Note the location of the `<<EOF` (no space between << and EOF), the `cd` is on a new line and followed by a newline with the `aprun` syntax and the final `EOF` in the set is without the leading `<<`, followed by a newline.

This syntax will execute each `qsub/aprun` command into a new batch node job submission.  Output from the script will be the series of job IDs requested.